# How do you breathe when giving a speech?

Tags: communication

I usually breathe through my mouth before giving a speech.

I do not intend this to relate to biology or health, but do you feel like it is better to breathe through the nose or mouth before talking?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not primarily about navigating the workplace.

Comment: Do you mean breathing between spoken sentences?  Then its the through mouth.   Or if you're asking about breathing in the time leading up to the speech?  This sounds more like a calming routine for public speaking and whatever lets you relax is best.

Comment: Just breathe as you normally do. I breathe through the nose. Anyway, it is not clear what help you need here. We cannot teach you how to breathe. ;)

Answer (score 3):

> do you feel like it is better to breathe through the nose or mouth before talking?

It's better to forget about breathing and just let it happen.